# Why does the current flow through a wire if the wire is an equipotential surface?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, electric-current, electrical-resistance, capacitance

From what I know, current flows across two points only if there is some potential difference across those two points. If that is the case, why does the current flow through a wire then?
See the picture for clarity:

As one can see, the potential is same on the left side of the wire. The current should not flow, yet it still does. Why?(I have the same question if the resistor was replaced by a capacitor.)
[image: ?]

Answer (score 0):

The voltage is not the same at all those points. There is a continual drop in voltage from the battery to the resistor along the wire because of the innate resistance in the wire. But for many purposes we ignore this and treat the wire as zero resistance, since it is usually much less than the resistance of the other circuit elements.

For example, the voltage along the wire might drop from 12 to 11.9 V from the battery + side to the resistor, and then from 11.9 to 6 V across the resistor.

Ideal circuits are an approximation, but the inaccuracies may be unimportant for a given application.